# Getting Percentage of 3 Entities with total number of entities in Mongoose? Taking total count from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a Node Express and Mongoose backend and i want to calculate the percentage of Pending, In-Progress and Complete requests to Total number of requests.

I have took count from db of total no of requests and divided it with 100 but i need to get count of Pending, In-Progress and Complete count as well.

```
totalcount: (req, res) => {
        UserRequest.countDocuments()

        .then(result => {
            if (!result) res.json({ success: false, result: "No result found"});

            res.json({success: true, result:  result / 100 });
        })
        .catch(err => res.json({success: false, result: err}))
    }
```

It should return:

> Pending: 30%
>   In-Progress: 40%
>   Complete: 30% as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use async-await. It'll be easier to structure the code.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/stack-overflow", { useNewUrlParser: true })

const UserReqSchema = new Schema({
    type: "String"
})
const UserReqModel = mongoose.model("UserReq", UserReqSchema)

async function counterFun() {
    try {
        const totalCount = await UserReqModel.countDocuments({})
        const pendingCount = await UserReqModel.countDocuments({ type: "pending" })
        const inprogressCount = await UserReqModel.countDocuments({ type: "inprogress" })
        const completeCount = await UserReqModel.countDocuments({ type: "complete" })

        console.log("pendingCount", (pendingCount/totalCount)*100);
        console.log("inprogressCount", (inprogressCount/totalCount)*100);
        console.log("completeCount", (completeCount/totalCount)*100);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
} 

counterFun()
```

Comment: Here you go. @AkshayKashid Edited the answer.